# CSS keyframe animation with translation transform snaps to whole pixels in IE 10 and Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

It appears both IE 10 and Firefox snaps elements to whole pixels when animating their position using translate 2d transform in a css keyframe animation.

Chrome and Safari does not, which looks *a lot* better when animating subtle movements.

The animation is done the following way:

```
@keyframes bobbingAnim {
   0% {
       transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
   }

   50% {
       transform: translate(0px, 12px);
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
   }

   100% {
       transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
   }
}
```

Here's an example of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/yZgTM/.

Just open it in Chrome and IE 10 (or Firefox) and you should notice the difference in smoothness of the motion.

I realise there might be many factors affecting this behaviour such as if the element is drawn with hardware acceleration or not.

**Does anyone know of a fix to try to force browsers to always draw the elements on subpixels?**

I found this similar question, but the answer was to animate using a translate transform, which is exactly what I'm doing:
[CSS3 Transitions 'snap to pixel'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917292/css3-transitions-snap-to-pixel).

**Update:**
After playing around a bit I found a fix for Firefox, doesn't do anything in IE 10 though. The trick is to scale down the element ever so slightly and use translate3d with a 1px offset in the Z-axis:

```
@keyframes bobbingAnim {
   0% {
       transform: scale(0.999, 0.999) translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
   }

   50% {
       transform: scale(0.999, 0.999) translate3d(0px, 12px, 1px);
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
   }

   100% {
       transform: scale(0.999, 0.999) translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
   }
}
```

Comment: Hm...I tested your original version on IE 10 and it seems to work just fine ! (Applying the fix makes IE 10 not smooth again.) Are you sure the original version (without "scale") isn't smooth on IE 10 ?

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. None of them are smooth in IE 10 for me. Thanks for reporting that it's not consistently "bad" in IE 10. I do wonder what the factors determining this behaviour is.

Comment: Actually, you are right. My first comment is inaccurate. I got confused by the fact that I consistently observe this behaviour in IE 10: When I load the jsFiddle and the animation starts, it is indeed not smooth. After I press "Run" in jsFiddle (without making any changes) then it loads again and this time the animation is smooth !?

Comment: I was hoping `document.msCSSOMElementFloatMetrics = true;` (which enables sub-pixel precision rendering in IE10) would do the trick, but it didn't manage to get it to work. I think I give up :(

Comment: Thanks for your efforts anyway!

Comment: Odd, it is smooth in IE 10 for me on first load using your jsfiddle.  Chrome is smooth, Firefox is jerky.

Comment: Robert, are you running Windows 7 or 8?

Comment: Adding a tiny twist it seems to enable sub-pixel rendering in Firefox (not tested in IE). 
`transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0.0001deg);` 
View [this edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZgTM/1/) in FF.

Comment: In fact you are not forced to move for 1px, you just need to use translate3d, even with only 0 as values. It enables hardware acceleration.

Comment: @FC': Usually 0 _does_ work to trigger hardware acceleration, but not in Firefox in this case. I tried with 0 first (always works with 0 on iOS for example).

Comment: @Strille Ok, good to know. You can also try something from this list : 
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    perspective: 1000; backface-visibility: hidden;
Each should enable acceleration, maybe one of these will work on firefox even with 0 as value. translateZ seems to be the best (seen on http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

Answer (score 6):

I love your question!
Good job in noticing the pixel-snap in firefox and IE10.

I've researched this subject a while ago and I advise you to check the GSAP forums, as they contain a lot of useful information on web animations.

Here's a topic regarding [IE10 pixel-snap issue](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/12698-scaling-animation-issues-in-ie10-and-11/).

What you need to do is add a minimal rotation to the element. This is so IE and Firefox will redraw it in a different way - which will stop pixel-snap for good :)

Tyr this:

```
@keyframes bobbingAnim {
  0% {
   transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotateZ(0.001deg);  
   animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate(0px, 12px) rotateZ(0.001deg);
    animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
  }

  100% {
   transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotateZ(0.001deg);
   animation-timing-function:ease-in-out
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nemanja is correct you will find that if you tweak the speed you will see better results this is fairly typical with css animations. Also it doesn't really make a difference in this case if you enable hardware acceleration. I tidied up the code a little bit and ran it without any issues, i do not have ie10; However, I have 11. You may have to just remove the second transform of translateZ if it doesn't run in 10

```
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.bobbing {
    position: absolute;  
    animation: bobbingAnim ease-in-out .5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bobbingAnim ease-in-out .5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bobbingAnim ease-in-out .5s infinite;    
}

.bobbing.text {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
}

.bobbing.image {
    left: 30px;
    top: 150px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x100/aa0000&text=Bobbing+image) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width: 310px;
    height: 110px;
}

@keyframes bobbingAnim {
   50% {
       transform: translate(0, 12px) translateZ(0);       
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bobbingAnim {
   50% {
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 12px, 0);       
   }
}

@-moz-keyframes bobbingAnim {
   50% {
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 12px, 0);       
   }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

There cant be **half a pixel** movement, there is no such thing.

Your problem is the speed and smoothness of the animation, not the "pixel snapping".

Comment: Ever heard of anti aliasing? Ever draw a curved line? A line that's not 0 or 180 degrees spun? Pixel snapping is definitely the problem :/

Comment: A nice example of pixel snapping: https://forum.unity.com/attachments/line-aa-gif.223415/