# CSS scale animation jerky in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have a save button that pulses when the form needs to be saved.

CSS:

```
@keyframes pulse-scale {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(1.1); }
}
.btn-alert {
  animation: 1s pulse-scale ease-out infinite alternate;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-round btn-alert">
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button>
```

The problem is that it plays poorly in Chrome 49. I'm sure it used to be fine, but now as it scales it seems to snap to certain pixel-aligned scales, and switch between fuzzy and sharp, resulting in a "jerky" animation. <del>It seems to be fine in Firefox 38</del> In Firefox 38 it plays fine initially, but after waiting for a while (?) or switching to another window and back it too plays poorly.

To be clear, this is an image sampling (quality) problem, not a framerate (speed) problem. Here's a video of how it looks. From left to right: Firefox, Firefox after a few minutes, Chrome. Only the one on the left is playing correctly.

[image]

Is there a CSS property I can set to make it play better - e.g. force it to use a different interpolation mode? I tried [adding `translateZ(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812911/css-keyframe-animation-with-translation-transform-snaps-to-whole-pixels-in-ie-10) to the keyframes, but it doesn't seem to help.

## [Demo in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohawe50r/3/)

Comment: did you try with @-webkit-   to?

Comment: @AdnanAkram I tried with `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-animation` - is that what you mean? But according to dev tools, those properties are ignored by my browser (superseded by `transform` and `animation`).

Comment: Doesn't look that jerky to me? I'm on Chrome 50 though. What do you mean by "jerky"? Also have you tried playing around with `ease-out` and trying some of the other settings? Also why are you using `animation` when you can use `transition`?

Comment: @aug I mean the image quality is poor, and it seems to shift from side to side as it plays. Updated question with a video. It's jerky on Chomium/Linux and for my colleague on Chrome/OS X. But Safari is fine. Can a transition repeat (play in a loop)?

Comment: How do you make that happen in your question?

Comment: @DaniSpringer.com CSS effect: see demo. Bug: run in old Chrome. Make animation: screen capture and ImageMagick. Embedded image: get more reputation, perhaps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this bug has something to do with Chrome 49 and is fixed if you upgrade to Chrome 50.

Comment: Thanks, but those changes don't fix the problem. It's not an issue of frame rate - I think it's an image sampling problem. I'll update the question to say that.

Comment: What kind of image is this? If possible, can you try using a vector-based image?

Comment: It's not a raster image - it's a `button` with rounded corners displaying a [vector font](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). The same problem happens if the button contains plain text.

Comment: This is driving me crazy. I feel like I should be able to fix this. What happens if you move the scale animation from `.btn-alert` to  `.btn-round`?

Comment: I tried putting them all into one class and it didn't help. Here's a [simplified demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ohawe50r/7/) with _only_ the animation property and one class (`.btn`). ... So are you able to reproduce the problem at all?

Comment: Eek, I just updated to Chrome 50 and it's fixed (on Linux)! I'll see if there's a difference between the computed properties in 49 and 50.

Comment: I'm having a heck of a time reproducing it on Mac/Chrome 50.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111379/discussion-between-z0r-and-andy-hoffman).

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: It's also buggy on Chrome 54 mac os. Tried everything, from will-change to backface-visibility, seems that I'll have to wait for a fix from Chrome team.